# Pass credentials file to Docker container CDK Pipeline

Tags: docker, aws-cdk, aws-fargate, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to build a CodePipeline that sets up Fargate. My container needs some secrets in order to access a third party storage and I'd like to pass on a file I create during CDK synth containing these secrets. For some reason when the pipeline gets to the docker build phase, it fails with the following message:

```
docker build --secret id=mysecrets,src=.mysecrets --tag cdkasset-f34f2e7f --file Dockerfile.aws . exited with error code 1: could not parse secrets: [id=mysecrets,src=.mysecrets]: failed to stat .mysecrets: stat .mysecrets: no such file or directory
```

My pipeline definition looks like as follows:

```
const synthStep = new GitHubStep('SynthStep', {
  env: {
    GITBRANCH: props.branchName,
  },
  input: sourceStep,
  commands: [
    'npm ci',
    `npm run cdk -- synth ${id}`,
    'echo TOKEN=${TOKEN} >> .mysecrets',
    'echo USER=${USER} >> .mysecrets',
  ],
});


const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
  codePipeline: rawPipeline,
  synth: synthStep,
  synthCodeBuildDefaults: {
    partialBuildSpec: BuildSpec.fromObject({
      env: {
        'secrets-manager': {
          TOKEN: `${NugetCredentialsArn}:NUGET_TOKEN`,
          USER: `${NugetCredentialsArn}:NUGET_USER`
        }
      },
    }),
  },
  codeBuildDefaults: {
    partialBuildSpec: BuildSpec.fromObject({
      env: {
        variables: {
          GITBRANCH: props.branchName,
        }
      }
    })
  },
  assetPublishingCodeBuildDefaults: {
    partialBuildSpec: BuildSpec.fromObject({
      env: {
        variables: {
          DOCKER_BUILDKIT: '1',
        }
      }
    })
  },
  publishAssetsInParallel: false,
  useChangeSets: false,
});
```

In the application step I try to use it this way:

```
taskDefinition.addContainer(service.name, {
  image: ContainerImage.fromDockerImageAsset(
    new DockerImageAsset(this, service.name, {
      directory: './App/Subfolder', 
      file: `Dockerfile.aws`,
      buildSecrets: {
        mysecrets: DockerBuildSecret.fromSrc('.mysecrets'),
      },
    }),
  )
```

Any idea why it can't find the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Had to copy the .mysecret file next to the container image file after creating it in the synth step.